# Browser freezes up when running JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I run this code, the window/tab freezes up and I'm not sure how to debug/fix it, help?

http://jsfiddle.net/z3DjY/1/

```
var levelArray = new Array();
var canvas;
var ctx;
var playerLocation;
var edge;
var elementEdge = 10; // Each element is 10x10 pixels
var workerArray;
var ghostLocationArray;

var levelArray = [
["player", "empty", "empty", "empty", "wall", "wall", "empty",
    "empty", "wall", "wall", "empty", "empty", "empty", "empty",
    "empty", "empty", "empty", "wall", "empty", "wall", "wall",
    "wall", "wall", "empty", "wall", "empty", "wall", "empty",
    "box", "wall", "empty", "wall", "empty", "empty", "empty",
    "empty", "empty", "empty", "wall", "wall", "wall", "empty",
    "wall", "wall", "empty", "empty", "ghost", "wall", "ghost"]
];

$(function () {
aBoyandhisBox.music = document.getElementById("music");
aBoyandhisBox.music.volume = 0.25;

// set the game state as "starting screen"
aBoyandhisBox.state = aBoyandhisBox.STATE_STARTING_SCREEN;
// start the game when clicking anywhere in starting screen
$('#game').click(function () {
    setTimeout(playMusic, 1000);
    if (aBoyandhisBox.state == aBoyandhisBox.STATE_STARTING_SCREEN) {
        $("#help").fadeOut();
        // change the state to playing.
        aBoyandhisBox.state = aBoyandhisBox.STATE_PLAYING;
        gameLoop();
    }
});

// get the reference of the context
canvas = document.getElementById('game');
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

console.log(levelArray[0]);

});
```

// This function fires once the page is done loading

```
function gameLoop() {
// Initializing all Global Variables
edge = Math.sqrt(levelArray.length);

// Canvas setup function calls here, including calls to assign input handlers
setupGhostWorkerArray();
setupCanvas(levelArray);

// Adding direct user input to a Canvas Element
canvas.addEventListener("keyup", keyHandler, false);
```

// The actual game loop

```
while (isPlayerAlive && boxFound) {
    addHumanPause();
    hauntLevel(levelArray);
}
}

function setupGhostWorkerArray() {
workerArray = new Array();
ghostLocationArray = new Array();
// Assuming a level has 2 ghosts
for (i = 0, j = 0; i < levelArray[0].length; i++) {
    if (levelArray[i] == "ghost") {
        ghostArray[j] = i;
        workerArray[j] = new Worker("gameWorker.js");
        j++;
    }
}
}

function setupCanvas(levelArray) {
var currentX = 0,
    currentY = 0;

emptyTile = document.getElementById('empty');
ghostTile = document.getElementById('ghost');
playerTile = document.getElementById('boy');
wallTile = document.getElementById('wall');
boxTile = document.getElementById('box');

for (var i = 0; i < edge; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < edge; j++) {
        switch (levelArray[i][j]) {
            case "empty":
                // empty location
                ctx.drawImage(emptyTile, currentX, currentY);
                break;
            case "wall":
                // wall block
                ctx.drawImage(wallTile, currentX, currentY);
                break;
            case "box":
                // box block
                ctx.drawImage(boxTile, currentX, currentY);
                break;
            case "ghost":
                // enemy sprite
                ctx.drawImage(ghostTile, currentX, currentY);
                break;
            case "player":
                // player sprite
                ctx.drawImage(playerTile, currentX, currentY);
                break;
        }
        currentX += elementEdge;
    }
    currentY += elementEdge;
}
}
```

// Function for handling movement: provide a direction for movement for a sprite in the
    level, and this level

// will reflect those changes on the Canvas. Movement involves moving the object one
    block in whichever direction specified

// Returns the updated array; no game logic here, items are just moved around

```
function moveObject(objectIndex, direction) {
// Calculate current X & Y co-ordinates based on objectIndex
var currentX = objectIndex % edge;
var currentY = parseInt(objectIndex / edge);
var changeY, changeX, indexChange;

switch (direction) {
    case "up":
        indexChange = objectIndex - edge;
        changeX = 0;
        changeY = elementEdge * -1;
        break;
    case "down":
        indexChange = objectIndex + edge;
        changeX = 0;
        changeY = elementEdge;
        break;
    case "left":
        indexChange = objectIndex - 1;
        changeX = elementEdge * -1;
        changeY = 0;
        break;
    case "right":
        indexChange = objectIndex + 1;
        changeX = elementEdge;
        changeY = 0;
        break;
}

var newIndex = objectIndex + indexChange;
//Only empty locations (or locations with a player on them) are valid for movement purposes
if (levelArray[newIndex] == "empty" || levelArray[newIndex] == "player" || levelArray[newIndex] == "box") {
    var appropriateTile;
    if (levelArray[ObjectIndex] == "ghost") {
        appropriateTile = document.getElementById("ghostTile");
        for (var i = 0; i < ghostLocationArray.length; i++) {
            if (ghostLocationArray[i] == objectIndex) ghostLocationArray[i] = newIndex;
        }
    } else {
        //Only other thing that can move is the player
        appropriateTile = document.getElementById("playerTile");
        playerLocation = objectIndex + indexChange;
    }

    levelArray[newIndex] = levelArray[objectIndex];
    levelArray[objectIndex] = "empty";

    ctx.drawImage(emptyTile, currentX, currentY);
    currentY += changeY;
    currentX += changeX;
    ctx.drawImage(appropriateTile, currentX, currentY);
}
}
```

// Player has not been eaten by a ghost

```
function isPlayerAlive(levelArray) {
return checkFor("player");
}
```

// Player has not stepped on a box

```
function boxFound(levelArray) {
return checkFor("box");
}

function checkFor(checkFor) {
var found = false;

for (var i = 0; i < levelArray.length; i++) {
    if (levelArray[i] == checkFor);
    found = true;
}

return found;
}
```

// Passes arrays into a worker's wander(), to get new positions for ghosts on the map

```
function hauntLevel(levelArray) {
var subArrayEdge = 7;
var arrayEdge = Math.sqrt(levelArray.length);
var ghostFound = false,
    subArray;

for (var i = 0, l = 0; i < levelArray.length; i++) {
    ghostFound = false;
    if (levelArray[i] == "ghost") {
        subArray = new Array();
        ghostFound = true;
        // Ghost found, start constructing a 7x7 composed of the blocks surrounding
        // the ghost (blocks out of bounds on the levelArray are represented as walls).
        // Start from the upper left corner, left to right, top to bottom(like a page in a book)
        var blockIndex = i - (arrayEdge * 3) - 3;
        for (var j = 0; j < 49; j++) //A 7x7 array will have 0-48 indices
        {
            for (var k = 0; k < subArrayEdge; k++) {
                if (blockIndex < 0 || blockIndex > (levelArray.length - 1)) {
                    subArray[j] = "wall";
                } else {
                    subArray[j] = levelArray[blockIndex];
                }
                blockIndex++;
            }
            // Next row, start from the left again
            blockIndex = blockIndex + arrayEdge - subArrayEdge;
        }
    }

    if (ghostFound) {
        workerArray[l].onmessage = function (event) {
            moveObject(ghostLocationArray[l], event.data);
        }
        workerArray[l].postMessage(subArray);
        l++;
    }
}
}

function keyHandler(theEvent) {
var direction;
switch (theEvent.keyCode) {
    case 87:
        // w key to move up
        direction = "up";
        break;
    case 83:
        // s key to move down
        direction = "down";
        break;
    case 65:
        // a key to move left
        direction = "left";
        break;
    case 68:
        // d key to move right
        direction = "right";
        break;
    case 82:
        // r key to restart the level
        // NOT IMPLEMENTED
        break;
    case 81:
        // q key to restart the game
        // NOT IMPLEMENTED
        break;
}

moveObject(playerLocation, direction);
}
```

Comment: You should debug your own code.

Comment: Start by using the developer tools in your preferred browser environment (Firebug, IE Developer Tools, Chrome Dev Tools) and putting in breakpoints in the JavaScript code to see when the execution reaches those points.

Comment: My first guess is that you've created an infinite loop in there somewhere. Check your while loop.

Comment: On Chromium I get `Uncaught InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable.` instead of an infinite loop

Comment: Slang for Chrome? I've never received that error before (in my life)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This blocks indefinitely.

```
while (isPlayerAlive && boxFound) {
    addHumanPause();
    hauntLevel(levelArray);
}
```

You want to set up your game loop as one "tick" event that fires every so often. Do all your logic and updating during that tick.

You've written a lot of code that shows you are capable, so I'm just going to point you at checking out setInterval or setTimeout rather than trying to piece all that together for you.

Good luck!

Also, never do this:

```
// Slow down the game to a human playable level
// Long Working Loop
function addHumanPause() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < 10000; j++) {
            // Do Nothing
        }
    }
}
```

All that does is spin the CPU for some length of time and doesn't let the browser respond to any events. Not even the important ones like, key press, or click, or "close this %#@$ it's making my lap burn!"